# Completar el for con las fechas de pago

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

En vista de que no pude solucionar mis dudas, en esta pregunta abarco un poco más lo que necesito para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Tengo esta función:

```
function getAmortizacion(monto, tasa, cuotas, periodo, tasa_tipo) {
 var valor_de_cuota = getValorDeCuotaFija(monto, tasa, cuotas, periodo, tasa_tipo);
 var saldo_al_capital = monto;
 var items = new Array();
 for (i=0; i < cuotas; i++) {
  interes = saldo_al_capital * getTasa(tasa, tasa_tipo, periodo);
  abono_al_capital = valor_de_cuota - interes;
  saldo_al_capital -= abono_al_capital;
  numero = i + 1;
  interes = interes.toFixed(2);
  abono_al_capital = abono_al_capital.toFixed(2);
  saldo_al_capital = saldo_al_capital.toFixed(2);
  totalCredito = cuotas * valor_de_cuota;
  item = [numero, interes, abono_al_capital, valor_de_cuota, saldo_al_capital];
  items.push(item);
 }
 var div2 = document.getElementById("input-value-total");
 totalCredito = totalCredito;
 div2.innerHTML = totalCredito;

 return items;
}
```

Todo esto lo pinto en una tabla:

```
<table id="table-2" class="table table-striped table-sm">
 <thead>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th>Cuota No.</th>
   <th>Interés</th>
   <th>Abono al capital</th>
   <th>Valor de la cuota</th>
   <th>Saldo al capital</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tbody_1" class="text-center"></tbody>
</table>
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, pero por más que busque soluciones, ninguna se adapta a lo que necesito; agregar un campo en la tabla que indique las fechas de pago, estas pueden ser mensuales (30 días) o quincenales (15 días):

`<label for="select-interests">Intereses</label><select id="select-periods" class="form-control" name="selectPeriods"><option value="mensual">Mensual</option><option value="quincenal">Quincenal</option></select>`

... hasta que se completen la cantidad de cuotas ingresadas ...

`<label for="select-dues">Cuotas</label><input id="select-dues" type="text" placeholder="Cuotas" required class="form-control" name="dues">`

y la fecha inicial (primera cuota) es ingresada en un input:

`<label>Fecha de primer pago</label><input id="input-date" type="date" name="dateFirstPayment" class="form-control">`

Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo básico aquí https://jsfiddle.net/pmnw4uLr/  Según entiendo la clave es que en el `for` tienes que hacer cuota*cantidad_de_días y eso te va dando las fechas que necesitas. Puedes empezar por una fecha que no sea hoy también.

```
for (i=0; i < CantidadDecuotas; i++) {

     var fecha = diaQueComienza.agregarDias(i*periodoEnDiasEntreCuotas)

 }
```

Dejo un bonus, que es, además de agregar días, como cambiar el formato de la fecha según estamos acostumbrados los no anglosajones:

```
Date.prototype.agregarDias = function(dias) {
    var fecha = new Date(this.valueOf());
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
    var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
    return fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options);
}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas garcias, me sirve para mejorar la función que tengo, pero realmente el problema es que no se como usarlo dentro de esa función que ya tengo.

Comment: @JhojanGuerrero en el fiddle hice una versión resumida de tu función, no puedo hacer exactamente la misma porque obviamente me faltan datos. pero básicamente tienes que agregar lo que pongo en el fiddle adentro de tu función. La salida también es distinta, pero es casi exactamente lo que necesitas creo, le tienes que agregar los td que faltan.